# How to get the Binary data of an input="file" server-side

Tags: asp-classic

What would change in this code?  It'sonly returning one line of data, theres got to be more than that for the file i selected, and if an image, how would i get the width/height of the image using this procedure?

```
 <%
 a=Request.TotalBytes
 b=Request.BinaryRead(a)
 Response.BinaryWrite(b)
 %>

 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" />
 <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Handling a binary upload in classic ASP is a little more complicated that just those three lines.
There is a project with source code available to handle binary uploads from classic ASP. Maybe  a look at that code will get you on your way. Otherwise, maybe the script itself is a solution for you:

http://www.freeaspupload.net/

http://www.freeaspupload.net/freeaspupload/viewsource.asp

Hope this helps,

Erik

Comment: +1 but it might also be worth mentioning that the `input type=file` needs a name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I have [written a script](http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/pure-asp-upload-script-with-additional-features-94647.html) in the past that handles file upload plus identifying image dimensions - feel free to use it as long as you keep all the copyright lines in place. (Parts are not my own writing)

If you have more specific question or problem, feel free to ask.